# mousemove reset counter jquery

Tags: jquery

Com este código, a página redireciona ao fim de 5 minutos se não existir ação, sendo que isso só acontece no refresh ou ao mudar de pagina, mas, pretendia que o counter fizesse um reset no movimento do mouse e teclado ao invés de ser na ação da página propriamente dita.

```js
function CountDown(duration, display) {
 if (!isNaN(duration)) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds; 
  var interVal=  setInterval(function () { 
   minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10); 
   seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10); 
   minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes; seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds; 

   $(display).html("<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>"); 
   if (--timer <= 0) {
    timer = duration; 
    SubmitFunction(); 
    $('#div').empty(); 
    clearInterval(interVal) 
   } 
  },1000);    
 } 
} 

function SubmitFunction(){ 
 $(location).attr('href', 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com');
} 

CountDown(300,$('#div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É simples, primeiro você deve definir a variável `interVal` fora do método `CountDown`, depois basta você definir no documento os eventos que deseja, limpar o intervalo de `interVal` e chamar novamente o método `CountDown`:

```
var interVal;
function CountDown(duration, display) {
  if (!isNaN(duration)) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    interVal = setInterval(function () {
...

$(document).on('mousemove click keyup', function(e) {
  clearInterval(interVal);
  CountDown(300, $('#div'));
});
```

#### Veja funcionando:

```js
var interVal;
function CountDown(duration, display) {
  if (!isNaN(duration)) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    interVal = setInterval(function () {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes; seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      $(display).html("<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>");
      if (--timer <= 0) {
        timer = duration;
        SubmitFunction();
        $('#div').empty();
        clearInterval(interVal)
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function SubmitFunction() {
  $(location).attr('href', 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com');
}

CountDown(300, $('#div'));

$(document).on('mousemove click keyup', function (e) {
  clearInterval(interVal);
  CountDown(300, $('#div'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: não só a resposta mas também a explicação.